# Selenium Page Object pattern error pages handling

Tags: selenium, junit, navigation, pageobjects

I've got a generic question concerning error pages.
Imagine a simple use case, good (1) and bad (2) authentication.

In case (1), we've got the index page.
In case (2), we've got a specific error page.

The point is, I've got a page object `LoginPage`, and the `submitLoginForm` should return the next page. I click on it with a bad login form filled in.

Then, we've got 2 options for handling it:
- should we create a `LoginErrorPage` and give `LoginPage` a `submitNonValidLoginForm` returning this `LoginErrorPage` ?
- should we use`LoginPage` with `submitLoginForm` returning the 'right' navigation page `IndexPage`, and in the Junit test, assert on the driver real state (hasn't got `IndexPage` elements but some others).

I hope I'm clear !
Thank you

Comment: It seems that you're not actually clear:) Do you want to test your authorization page and ask whether it is possible to use single method to check both successful and failed authorization cases or not?

Comment: In a nutshell, my question is where to put the assertion: In JUnit test directly, on the driver state (check element) OR using a check (in constructor for example) of the new class `LoginErrorPage`. I can edit my question if you want ?

Comment: You don't need to check page elements. Just use `driver.getCurrentUrl()` to check if `submitLoginForm` returned `index` page or `error` page.

Comment: That's OK if the URL are differents and I've some cases where it's not true

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience I can say it tends to be better to have different Page Objects for (conceptually) different pages, even when we're talking about the same URL with different content.

So I suggest following your first option, creating a `LoginError` Page Object. Another thing is that the page validation should be done in your Page Object, not as a test because your creating a dependency between the test and Selenium directly.

I.E (in a very pseudocodish way)

```
class BasePage {
    constructor (driver, context, isLoaded = false) {
        this->webDriver = driver

        //clicking links or submitting forms from other page objects 
        //will trigger the page load at driver level so we don't want to trigger a page reload  
        if (isLoaded) {
            this->loadPage()
        }

        this->validatePage()
    }

    loadPage() {
        this->webDriver->get(this->getPageUrl)
    }

    abstract validatePage()
    abstract getPageUrl()
}


class LoginPage extends BasePage{

    validatePage() {
        this->elementUsername = this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('username'))
        this->elementPassword = this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('password'))
        this->elementSubmit = this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('submit'))
    }
    getPageUrl() {
        return '/login/'
    }

    fillUser(value) {
        this->elementUsername->sendKeys(value)
    }

    fillPassword(value) {
        this->elementPassword->sendKeys(value)
    }

    submitValid() {
        this->elementSubmit->submit()
        return new DashboardPage(this->webDriver, this->context, true)
    }

    submitInvalid() {
        this->elementSubmit->submit()
        return new LoginErrorPage(this->webDriver, this->context, true)
    }
}

class DashboardPage extends BasePage {
    validatePage() {
        this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('welcomeMessage'))
    }

    getPageUrl() {
        return '/dashboard/'
    }
}
```

At this point your tests will only have to sort out the webdriver fixture but don't have to know anything about your pages

```
testValidCredentials:
    login = new LoginPage(..)
    login->fillUser('john')
    login->fillPassword('aa')
    dashboard = login->submitValid()

testInvalidCredentials:
    login = new LoginPage(..)
    login->fillUser('john')
    login->fillPassword('aa')
    loginError = login->submitInvalid()

testWelcomeMessage:
    dashboard = new DashboardPage(..)
    // a bad (but short enough) example, don't actually do this 
    assert(true, regexp('welcome', dashboard->getSource))
```

L.E.
From a testing perspective you have to know your expected result. Another approach would be to have a single submit that accepts expected page object as param

```
testInvalidCredentials:
    login = new LoginPage(..)
    login->fillUser('john')
    login->fillPassword('aa')
    loginError = login->submit('LoginErrorPage')
    assertContains('invalid login', loginError->getErrorMessages())
```

But after writing 100 tests you'll find this to be too verbose and, if the page received after a successful submit changes, you'll have a lot of rewriting to do.

Comment: That was what I started. So, we need to create a page for each error case, and then put in the assertions (not really 'assert' but some checks). But something bothers me: Page Objects should represent the page with available user actions right ? So there's not really submitValid or submitInvalid, just submit. And in this case, the JUnit test should contain the assertion, because submit returns the theoretically next page. I'm a bit confused now

Comment: A small trade-off  for the sake of encapsulating logic in your Page Objects. You'll find the same issue with submitting an invalid form that returns the same page. I.E. create a new account... if user inputs wrong data submitInvalid should return a new `self` page (and obviously you should provide some generic mechanism for checking messages present in a page, `getErrorMessages()` or such)

Comment: @buzz2buzz One other thing that just crossed my mind. My assumption was that your `LoginError` page is a different page than `Login` (URL or structure). If it's just the `LoginPage` with an error message then you don't create a new page, you just make a mechanism to check the presence of messages (error/info) in the page